# Two radio button getting selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I have a set of radio button (yes or no) the value gets rendered from database as boolean , if the db value is true then set the radio button yes to selected else no. And also right now when I click on yes both yes and no are getting selected.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group form-group--float">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input type="radio" name="sp" id="customRadio1" asp-for="SPLimit" value="1" >
                        <label class="radio__label" for="customRadio1">Yes</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="sp" id="customRadio2" asp-for="SPLimit" value="0">
                        <label class="radio__label"  for="customRadio2">No</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working demo:

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool SPLimit { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.SPLimit)
    {
        <input type="radio" name="sp" id="customRadio1" asp-for="@item.SPLimit" value="1">
        <label class="radio__label" for="customRadio1">Yes</label>
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="radio" name="sp" id="customRadio2" asp-for="@item.SPLimit" value="0">
        <label class="radio__label" for="customRadio2">No</label>
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MvcProjContext _context;

    public HomeController(MvcProjContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _context.Test.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How do you set values when you get db result? And what is sent or whatever you doing with it?
Try to send logs to find out the value of both. Maybe it's just display/design problem.